# (Discord v14) discord bot doesn't replies the message pong

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js, message

I'm making a simple discord bot that replies certain messages like some user said "ping" than the bot replies message "pong" so this is the source code

````
const { Client, Events, GatewayIntentBits, Message } = require('discord.js');
const { token } = require('./config.json');

// Create a new client instance
const client = new Client({ intents: [GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages] });

// When the client is ready, run this code (only once)
// We use 'c' for the event parameter to keep it separate from the already defined 'client'
client.once(Events.ClientReady, c => {
    console.log(`Ready! Logged in as ${c.user.tag}`);
});
//client.on("debug", console.log)

client.on('messageCreate', (message => {
    if (message.content === 'ping') {
        message.reply('pong')
    }
}))

client.on('error', console.error);

// Log in to Discord with your client's token
client.login(token);```

when I tested I said ping on the discord chat but the bot didn't replied. I gave the bot admin permission so there should not be a permission problem can anybody give me some answer about this problem?
the version of discord.js is **discord.js@14.13.0**
````

Answer (score -1):

### `MessageContent` Intent

Your bot requires the `MessageContent` intent to view & reply to messages.

```js
const client = new Client({
    intents: [
        GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages,
        GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent // add this
    ]
});
```

### Privileged Intents

Also enable the following intents on the [developer portal](https://discord.com/developers/applications)

[image: privileged intents]